# Javascript - condense multiple document.getelementbyid optimization

Tags: javascript, optimization

Is there any execution speed advantage to condense individual elements into an array as below and then call e instead of document.get....?  Other than shorten the loading time of the script. TIA.

FROM

```
document.getElementById('id1')
document.getElementById('id2')
document.getElementById('id3')
```

TO

```
var e=document.getElementById("id1","id2","id3");
```

edit: I mean getElementById, not some specialized tags.

Comment: What does `getElementsByIds` do? Is it your implementation?

Comment: the _document.getElementsByIds_ does not exist in the Javascript DOM spec. What is your goal? what browser are you aiming for? What is the execution speed advantage? 0.001 ms?

Comment: There cannot be any speed advantage in doing that. As others have said, there's no native `getElementsByIds()` method, so you'll end up with the same number of calls to `getElementById()`, with the additional overhead taken by the array construction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways to do this could be:

```
//return an array of elements
function elementsById(ids){
  var idsget = [].slice.call(arguments), result = [];
  for (var i=0;i<idsget.length;i=i+1){
    result.push(document.getElementById(idsget[i]);
  }
  return result;
}
var els = elementsById('id1','id2','id3');
// retrieve using els[0], els[1] etc.

// return an object
function elementsById(ids){
  var idsget = [].slice.call(arguments), result = {};
  for (var i=0;i<idsget.length;i=i+1){
    result[idsget[i]] = document.getElementById(idsget[i]);
  }
  return result;
}
var els = elementsById('id1','id2','id3');
// retrieve using els.id1, els.id2 etc.
```

It won't gain speed initially (`document.getElementById` is called as many times as it would be referencing the elements without a storage function), but will be more efficient if you subsequently need the elements in the remainder of your script.

Comment: Thanks, I will probably come back to this later, but I am still learning the basics and not fully appreciate this code.

Comment: Maybe this jsfiddle gives you an idea of the way it works: http://jsfiddle.net/w5HMn/

Answer (score 1):

if you have lots of calls to `document.getElementById` and want to shorten the document size you could declare a function like this:

```
function $(s){
    return document.getElementById(s);
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you explain more on how to use it? Thanks

Comment: @Jamex: You simply use `$` instead of `document.getElementById` in your code, for example `var e = $('SomeId');`.

Comment: Thanks, I also just read that the $ still does traverse document.getelementbyid each time.  As I understand it, this will cut down the code, but won't improve processing speed, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the references multiple times, you can put them in variables:

```
var id1 = document.getElementById('id1');
var id2 = document.getElementById('id2');
var id3 = document.getElementById('id3');
```

Using the variable instead of calling `getElementById` each time is a bit faster. Putting the references in an array is just a variation of this.

Note however that the variable (or array) contains the reference to the element that existed when you assigned it, if the element is removed and recreated you will have a reference to an element that doesn't exist in the page any more.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of the basics behind the var assignment